# How can I send multiple parameters in return response json in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to send multiple parameters in return function of laravel with json like this

````
$var1='value1';
$var2='value2';
return response()->json($var1, $var2);```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

send it in **array**

```
return response()->json([$value1, $value2]);
```

**Another way.**

You need to add `use Response;`

Only then you can successfully retrieve your data with

```
$data = [$value1, $value2];

return Response::json($data);
```

you can pass status as well.

```
return Response::json($data,200);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $var['value1']='value1';
  $var['value2']='value2';
  return response()->json([$var]);
```

you can also do it this way